# Exact time remaining to next quiz

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I can get only the currently ongoing quiz. How to display the exact time only until the next quiz?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, whether I got your question right: "I can get only the currently ongoing quiz." Does that mean, you have the ID of the currently ongoing quiz or that you can determine this quiz by comparing its start and end with the current time?

In first case, you can do:

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(b.start, a.end)
FROM <table> AS a
LEFT JOIN <table> AS b ON b.id_quiz <> a.id_quiz AND b.start > a.end
WHERE a.id_quiz = <current quiz id>
ORDER BY b.start ASC
LIMIT 1
```

In second case, it's even easier:

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(x.start, NOW())
FROM <table> AS x
WHERE x.start > NOW()
ORDER BY x.start ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Bartek's question has NOW() as parameter, not current quiz id

Comment: @Dan, I cannot see any `NOW()` in the question. Anyway, thanks for your hint. Maybe I didn't get the question totally right, so I edited my answer in that direction.

Comment: don't want to sound like a dick, but you should compare using >=

Answer (score 1):

subtract now from start?

```
-(now()-start)?
```